# Trouble with a single click on my button. Click event working only for double click

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I have some problems with click event. I'm new in javascript. When I click once, nothing happened, but for double click my event is working.

I'm tried figure out similar request from stackoverflow, but I don't understand yet, why it's happened with click event.

```js
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const sadness = document.getElementById('btn-sadness');
  const happynes = document.getElementById('btn-happy');

  sadness.disabled = true;

  happynes.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const x = document.querySelector('.image');

    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  display: none;
  width: 170px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="image" src="test-img.JPG" alt="img">
    <button id="btn-happy">Happy</button>
    <button id="btn-sadness">Sadness</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=click+twice+toggle+hide+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: to make it simpler. just add `hidden` on the image and do `x.hidden = !x.hidden`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is fine, it's a behaviour of browsers. Browsers check if there are styles that hide the image (like `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`) and based on that they will (or will not) load the image. In your case the image is `display: none` on page load thats why the image is not loaded and the `if(x.style.display === 'none')` returns `false` and will execute the `else` block. The block interacts with the image which downloads the image but it's still not visible as the else block sets `display: none`. Thats why you need a double click to make the image visible. To fix this you could just check if the image is visible rather than checking if it is not.

```js
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    const sadness = document.getElementById('btn-sadness');
    const happynes = document.getElementById('btn-happy');

    sadness.disabled = true;

    happynes.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
        const x = document.querySelector('.image');

        if(x.style.display === 'block'){
            x.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.container{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.image-container{
    display: inline-block;
}

img{
    display: none;
    width: 170px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image" src="https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" alt="img">
        <button id="btn-happy">Happy</button>
        <button id="btn-sadness">Sadness</button>
    </div>
</div>
```